# How to let user crop the image using Picasso?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, picasso

I am using Picasso to get the image but it sometimes rotates the image to fit it in the image view. Also, I want to let the user decide which part of the image should be cropped. Is there a way I could do it? Please suggest how to code it or some link I could refer to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It's highly likely that the rotation issue is because the image is an Exif image ([probable issue](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/846)).

Picasso allows for a few image transformations. Here's an [article](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit) about it.

[Picasso Transformations](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations) provides a variety of image transformations for Picasso.

If that doesn't suit your needs, you can always use an android image cropping library like [uCrop](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop) or [android crop](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop) or [cropper](https://github.com/steelkiwi/cropiwa) or any of the dozen other cropping libraries available on github.
If you're going to be using an android image cropping library, then I'd suggest that you use [ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) (assuming it suits your needs ofcourse) since it comes with it's own built-in `CropImageActivity` which will probably make your job much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to call crop intent or you could implement your own cropping activity but i suggest you use a library if you want this one is simple https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper or you could use https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop but the quality is lower using uCrop.